# metricbeat unable to send data - write: connection reset by peer

Tags: ssl, logstash, metricbeat

I am trying to send sys metric with metricbeat to my logstash server on SSL.

When I try connecting the server logstash port I can connect but in metricbeat logfile I am getting following error:

```
2017-03-10T12:27:22Z ERR Failed to publish events caused by: write tcp [private_ip]:51105->[logstash-public-ip]:5044: write: connection reset by peer

2017-03-10T12:27:22Z INFO Error publishing events (retrying): write tcp [private_ip]:51105->[logstash-public-ip]:5044 write: connection reset by peer
```

There is no SSL related error. client and servers are able to connect and authenticate each other with their names and the SSL certificate. There are issues with read failed for filebeat on elasticsearch site but the method couldn't solve the issue.
Any help would be great

Comment: Can you reach that host and port from the machine that metricbeat is on? Could there be a firewall in the way? Are you using the beats input on the Logstash you are sending to?

Comment: Yes. I can connect to both machines from logstash server. and with telnet from other servers at the logstash port. I even get some data from those servers at logstash end. but this error remains.

Comment: What is the version of Logstash?

Comment: 5.1.2 for both metricbeat and logstash

Comment: There have been a lot of issues with timeouts that caused similar problem for many people. I would suggest increasing the `client_inactivity_timeout` in logstash config file to a value that could eliminate timeouts problem (like 86400 for 24h, or 0 to disable it totally).

Comment: but it'll keep the faulty sessions open from logstash's side. not sure if the new events are received in same session or new one is created. But this might work till new problem occurs

Comment: If increasing this timeout will help, then you might adjust it to avoid having it increased that much. Check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a lot of issues with timeouts that caused similar problem for many people. I would suggest increasing the `client_inactivity_timeout` in logstash config file to a value that could eliminate timeouts problem (like `86400` for `24h`, or `0` to `disable` it totally)

Comment: there is no client_inactivity_timeout setting in logstash.yaml

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your comment. Have a look at this PR: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-beats/pull/108

Comment: when i add that field in logstash.yaml get error - related to undefined one and this is not an option for configuration in the beats input plugin. can you please confirm where should i add this